# How do I join the values of two DataFrame columns as one

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `data` with these columns `col1` and `col1.1`.

```
data:
ID     Col1    Col1.1
1      21      Water, Salt
13     18      Onions
101    30      Replaceable with oil, water, acid
```

I want `data` to be:

```
data:
ID     Col1
1      21: Water, Salt 
13     18: Onions
101    30: Replaceable with oil, water, acid
```

So far, I have:

```
data['Col'] = ': '.join(str(list(zip(data['Col1'], data['Col1.1']))).split("', ")).replace("'", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
```

NOTE: I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning` on running this.

How do I go about this? Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [str.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df['Col1'].astype(str).str.cat(df['Col1.1'], sep=': ')
Out: 
0                          21: Water, Salt
1                               18: Onions
2    30: Replaceable with oil, water, acid
```

You need to assign this back and drop the other column to get exactly the same output:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].astype(str).str.cat(df['Col1.1'], sep=': ')
df = df.drop('Col1.1', axis=1)
```

Or, all in one line, thanks to [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696078/how-do-i-join-the-values-of-two-dataframe-columns-as-one/45696160#comment78350639_45696160):

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].astype(str).str.cat(df.pop('Col1.1'), sep=': ')
```

Comment: or maybe do it in one step: `df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].astype(str).str.cat(df.pop('Col1.1'), sep=': ')`

Comment: @MaxU Good idea! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ayhan and @MaxU. however,the change isn't permanent. I know this because when I write `data` to a csv file, only `Col1` and its values are pesent. In other words, I loose data from `Col1.1` - which is the last thing I want

Comment: @CodeLearner In your desired output there was no Col1.1 so I assumed you want to remove it. If not, do not execute the `df = df.drop('Col1.1', axis=1)`  line. `df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].astype(str).str.cat(df['Col1.1'], sep=': ')`  should be enough.